When to use getServerSideProps for connected graphql search component
When to Use getServerSideProps Function?
I have a situation where I've created a search result component using the getServerSideProps function. In this function, I'm calling a GraphQL API to fetch data.
However, I've noticed that the getServerSideProps function is not getting called as expected when the component loads.
Can anyone help explain the execution flow of getServerSideProps and provide insights into why it might not be getting called during the component's load?

Can you please share your overall project is SSG or SSR?
You can check in [[..path]].tsx file

It's configured as SSR

I was saying same that you can not merge SSG and SSR together.
now if it is ssr then getServerSideProps should work can you please share code

getServerSideProps on your component can only be used when the page the component is used on is setup for SSR (Server Side Rendering).
The getStaticProps and getServerSideProps methods on components is a function provided by the Next.js JSS SDK. Based on your pages rendering method, it will check if those methods exist on the component and call them.
If you want to get data at the component level and your page is SSG, you need to use the getStaticProps method on the component. The function will be executed when the page is generated.
If you need a page that is always rendered server side on each request, you will need to create a route in your Next.js app that uses getServerSideProps, then your components used on that route can also use getServerSideProps. This type of page should be very rare tho, there are very few use cases where SSG would not work. For example, a user profile page might want to be SSR, or something where the data would be 100% unique to every user.
Based on your tags, if you are looking to build a search results page, this should be SSG and then call the search API on the client to populate the results. There is no need to SSR a search results page.
